# Pass components as props to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create an "AB Test" component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const AbTest = ({ components, criteriaToMatch }) => {
  let componentToRender;

  components.forEach((component) => {
    if (component.criteria === criteriaToMatch) {
      componentToRender = component.instance;
    }
  });

  return componentToRender;
};

AbTest.propTypes = {
  components: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    instance: PropTypes.func,
    criteria: PropTypes.any,
  })),
  criteriaToMatch: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.bool,
    PropTypes.string,
    PropTypes.number,
  ]),
};

export default AbTest;
```

You'll then use it like this:

```
import MyComponentA from '../my-component-a';
import MyComponentB from '../my-component-b';

<AbTest
  components={[
    { instance: MyComponentA, criteria: 'A' },
    { instance: MyComponentB, criteria: 'B' },
  ]}
  criteriaToMatch="A"
/>
```

So you'll pass it an array of components each having some criteria, and which ever matches gets rendered. But I'm getting an error saying:

> Functions are not valid as a React child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From AbTest component, you must return the component instance like

```
const AbTest = ({ components, criteriaToMatch }) => {
  let ComponentToRender;

  components.forEach((component) => {
    if (component.criteria === criteriaToMatch) {
      ComponentToRender = component.instance;
    }
  });

  return <ComponentToRender />;
};
```